# Name of Principle Giving Precedence to a More General Hypothesis

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method

As far as I know, there is a principle that gives precedence to a theory that is more general than a more specific one, i.e the more general one is more acceptable.
What is the name of that principle?

Comment: Similar to [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) : "simpler solutions are more likely to be correct than complex ones."

Comment: More general, as in explaining wider range of phenomena (other things being equal)? Unification, one of the [epistemic values in theory choice](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-objectivity/#EpiConVal), dictates it.